# Empty/delete a session object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-variables, session-timeout

How do I empty a session object after rendering a specific path?

I have one view method in my controller:

```
def view
    session[:storeid] = params[:id]
    redirect_to products_path
end
```

I want to empty `session[:storeid]` after the products_path has been displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the last line of the products_path view file add this code

```
<% session.delete(:storeid) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...This s what am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

to empty a session use

```
session[:storeid] = nil
```